# Laravel 5.2 :get checkbox checked

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I am trying to get checkbox as checked

Here is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('extra_services', 'Add extra services') !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php var_dump (array($temp->extra_services))?>
                    @foreach($extra as $ext)
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                {!! Form::hidden('extra_services', 0) !!}
                                <input type="checkbox" name="extra_services[]" value="{!! $ext->id !!}"
                                       {!! in_array($ext->id, array($temp->extra_services)) ? 'checked' : '' !!} >
                                {!! $ext->title !!}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Edit**
here is my edit controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $temp = Template::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $extra = TempExtraService::all();
        return view('admin.templates.tempDetails.edit', compact('temp', 'extra'));
    }
```

here is my update controller

```
public function update(Requests\TemplateRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $temp->extra_services = implode($request->extra_services, ',');
        $temp->save();
        return Redirect::back()->with('states', 'Templates has been updated successfully');
    }
```

when I dump my `$temp->extra_services` I got `array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "1,2" }`

but in the view the first checkbox only checked the second is not which it should be check too.

what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: just down vote the question don't mean I understood where my mistake please describe.

Comment: You need to add some more information. What is the contents of  $temp->extra_services ?

Comment: I mention in my question it's an array `when I dump my $temp->extra_services I got array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "1,2" }` anyway will add the controller to the question

Comment: @Jason see my question edit hope this will help

Comment: You have `extra_services` as a single hidden field and `extra_services[]` as an array. I'm pretty sure that's a recipe for inconsistent behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do *array($temp->extra_services)* you are not creating the array as you expect.

```
var_dump(array($temp->extra_services)); // shows ["1,2"]
```

What you want is to create an array from a comma separated string

```
var_dump(explode(",", $temp->extra_services)); // Show [1,2]
```

Use this second one in your *in_array* and you should be good to go.